# trying to get response from CAS secure rest api,but getting login page as response from java client

Tags: java, authentication, cas, shiro

I am trying to get correct response from CAS secure rest api,but every time i am getting login page as a response , i have converted groovy rest client from this site https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casum/restful+api into java rest client but it is not giving correct result, 
below is my java rest client for CAS .

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public String getTicketGrantingTicket(String server, String username, String password) {


        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server);
        post.setParameter("username", username);
        post.setParameter("password", password);
//        NameValuePair[] nameValuePairs = new NameValuePair[2];
//        nameValuePairs[0] = new NameValuePair("username", username);
//        nameValuePairs[1] = new NameValuePair("password", password);

//        post.setRequestBody(nameValuePairs);
        try {
            client.executeMethod(post);
            String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOG.info("Response is : " + response);
            switch (post.getStatusCode()) {
            case 201:
                Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(".*action=\".*/(.*?)\".*").matcher(response);
                if (matcher.matches())
                    return matcher.group(1);
                LOG.warning("Successful ticket granting request, but no ticket found!");
                LOG.info("Response (1k): " + response.substring(0, Math.min(1024, response.length())));
                break;
            default:
                LOG.warning("Invalid response code " + post.getStatusCode() + " from CAS server!");
                LOG.info("Response: " + response);
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String getServiceTicket(String server, String ticketGrantingTicket, String service) {
        if (ticketGrantingTicket.isEmpty())
            return null;
//        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server + "/" + ticketGrantingTicket);
        post.setParameter("service",service);
//        NameValuePair[] nameValuePairs = new NameValuePair[1];
//        nameValuePairs[0] = new NameValuePair("service", service);
//        post.setRequestBody(nameValuePairs);

        try {
            client.executeMethod(post);
            String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOG.info("Service Response is : " + response);
            switch (post.getStatusCode()) {
            case 200:
                return response;
            default:
                LOG.warning("Invalid response code ( $post.getStatusCode() ) from CAS server!");
                LOG.info("Response (1k): " + response.substring(0, Math.min(1024, response.length())));
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String validateServiceTicket(String server, String serviceTicket, String service) {
        if (serviceTicket.isEmpty())
            return null;
//        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(server + "/" + serviceTicket);
        post.setParameter("service", service);
        post.setParameter("ticket", serviceTicket);
//        NameValuePair[] nameValuePairs = new NameValuePair[2];
//        nameValuePairs[0] = new NameValuePair("service", service);
//        nameValuePairs[1] = new NameValuePair("ticket", serviceTicket);

//        post.setRequestBody(nameValuePairs);

        try {
            client.executeMethod(post);
            String response = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOG.info("validate Response is : " + response);
            switch (post.getStatusCode()) {
            case 200:
                return response;
            default:
                LOG.warning("Invalid response code "+ post.getStatusCode()+" ");
                LOG.info("Response (1k): " + response.substring(0, Math.min(1024, response.length())));
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void getServiceCall(String service, String serviceTicket) {
//        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(service);
        NameValuePair[] nameValuePair = new NameValuePair[1];
        nameValuePair[0] = new NameValuePair("ticket", serviceTicket);

        method.setQueryString(nameValuePair);
        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);
            String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOG.info("Service Request call is  : " + response);
            switch (method.getStatusCode()) {
            case 200:
                LOG.info("Response: " + response);
                break;
            default:
                LOG.warning("Invalid response code (" + method.getStatusCode() + ") from CAS server!");
                LOG.info("Response: $response");
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    public void logout(String server, String ticketGrantingTicket) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        DeleteMethod method = new DeleteMethod(server + "/" + ticketGrantingTicket);
        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);
            String response = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            LOG.info("logout response is  : " + response);
            switch (method.getStatusCode()) {
            case 200:
                LOG.info("Logged out");
                break;
            default:
                LOG.warning("Invalid response code (" + method.getStatusCode() + ") from CAS server!");
                LOG.info("Response: $response");
                break;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            LOG.warning(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestServiceAuthenticator authentication = new RestServiceAuthenticator();
        String server = "https://casserver.com/cas/v1/tickets";
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String service = "http://servicetogetresponse";
        String validate = "https://casserver.com/cas/validate";
        // Client client = new Client();
//        String ticketGrantingTicket = authentication.getTicketGrantingTicket(server, username, password);
//        System.out.println("TicketGrantingTicket is " + ticketGrantingTicket);
//        String serviceTicket = authentication.getServiceTicket(server, ticketGrantingTicket, service);
//        System.out.println("ServiceTicket is " + serviceTicket);
        authentication.validateServiceTicket(validate, serviceTicket, service);
//        authentication.getServiceCall(service, serviceTicket);
//        authentication.logout(server, ticketGrantingTicket);
    }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you use Shiro, you should use [buji-pac4j](https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j) + [pac4j-cas](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j) to deal with the CAS REST API -> https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/wiki/Clients#cas-support-pac4j-cas-module

Comment: Thanks, i am planning to use pac4j now.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to use the pac4j mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/pac4j-users if you have any issue